# r merge by id and date between two dates

Tags: r, date, merge, dplyr

I have **dataset1** which has two columns `ID` and `Application_SubmittedDate`. The Application_SubmittedDate column is a date/time column.

```
     ID         Application_SubmittedDate
     6972        2001-05-30 16:57:00
     6972        2003-03-08 12:30:00
     6972        2006-03-22 17:43:00
     6972        2003-08-07 20:20:00
     6972        2006-07-28 18:28:00
     6972        2001-05-25 17:14:00
     6972        2003-09-30 00:48:00
     6972        2002-06-04 18:11:00
     6972        2006-05-06 17:30:00
     6972        2003-02-24 16:02:00
     6972        2006-09-16 16:29:00
     6972        2003-02-12 22:47:00
     6972        2002-08-15 23:30:00
     6972        2002-08-31 22:32:00
     40841       2002-09-27 05:39:00
     40841       2002-01-08 09:05:00
     40841       2002-10-07 21:04:00
     40841       2002-08-17 18:50:00
     59547       2003-08-12 10:45:00
     59547       2001-02-20 17:02:00
     59547       2002-11-05 23:01:00
     60861       2003-10-27 14:40:00
     63457       2001-12-05 04:16:00
     65048       2002-12-16 10:18:00
     65048       2003-12-29 17:52:00
     65048       2005-02-20 16:58:00
     67037       2004-01-01 18:18:00
     67037       2006-06-22 01:04:00
     67037       2004-07-31 18:30:00
     67037       2004-08-04 14:09:00
     67037       2005-04-20 18:06:00
     67037       2006-06-15 16:55:00

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 
6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 6972L, 40841L, 
40841L, 40841L, 40841L, 59547L, 59547L, 59547L, 60861L, 63457L, 
65048L, 65048L, 65048L, 67037L, 67037L, 67037L, 67037L, 67037L, 
67037L), Application_SubmittedDate = structure(c(991241820, 1047126600, 
1143049380, 1060287600, 1154111280, 990810840, 1064882880, 1023214260, 
1146936600, 1046102520, 1158424140, 1045090020, 1029454200, 1030833120, 
1033105140, 1010480700, 1034024640, 1029610200, 1060685100, 982688520, 
1036537260, 1067265600, 1007525760, 1040033880, 1072720320, 1108918680, 
1072981080, 1150938240, 1091298600, 1091628540, 1114020360, 1150390500
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Application_SubmittedDate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
18L, 35L, 52L, 69L, 86L, 103L, 137L, 154L, 188L, 205L, 239L, 
256L, 273L, 290L, 300L, 305L, 310L, 315L, 327L, 339L, 351L, 352L, 
353L, 359L, 371L, 389L, 400L, 411L, 422L, 466L, 477L))
```

The **second dataset** is has three columns `ID` , `Application_ProcessStartDate`, `Application_ProcessEndDate`. These two Applicateion ProcessStarDate and EndDate columns are date/time columns.

```
    ID     Application_ProcessStartDate Application_ProcessEndDate
    65048  2005-02-20 12:44:22          2005-02-23 06:07:45       
    65048  2006-06-21 17:31:45          2006-06-24 01:42:41       
    111993 2006-06-21 17:31:45          2006-06-24 01:42:41      




    df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(65048L, 65048L, 111993L), Application_ProcessStartDate = structure(c(1108903462, 
1150911105, 1150911105), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Application_ProcessEndDate = structure(c(1109138865, 1151113361, 
    1151113361), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Application_ProcessStartDate", "Application_ProcessEndDate"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I am aiming for is to merge First) By ID 2) Within those ID merge those from df1 where Application_SubmittedDate value is between `Application_ProcessStartDate`, `Application_ProcessEndDate` values.

The final results would look like this

```
         ID         Application_SubmittedDate   Application_ProcessStartDate    Application_ProcessEndDate
         6972        2001-05-30 16:57:00
         6972        2003-03-08 12:30:00
         6972        2006-03-22 17:43:00
         6972        2003-08-07 20:20:00
         6972        2006-07-28 18:28:00
         6972        2001-05-25 17:14:00
         6972        2003-09-30 00:48:00
         6972        2002-06-04 18:11:00
         6972        2006-05-06 17:30:00
         6972        2003-02-24 16:02:00
         6972        2006-09-16 16:29:00
         6972        2003-02-12 22:47:00
         6972        2002-08-15 23:30:00
         6972        2002-08-31 22:32:00
         40841       2002-09-27 05:39:00
         40841       2002-01-08 09:05:00
         40841       2002-10-07 21:04:00
         40841       2002-08-17 18:50:00
         59547       2003-08-12 10:45:00
         59547       2001-02-20 17:02:00
         59547       2002-11-05 23:01:00
         60861       2003-10-27 14:40:00
         63457       2001-12-05 04:16:00
         65048       2002-12-16 10:18:00
         65048       2003-12-29 17:52:00         
         65048       2005-02-20 16:58:00         2005-02-20 12:44:22          2005-02-23 06:07:45  
         65048            NA                     2006-06-21 17:31:45          2006-06-24 01:42:41 
         67037       2004-01-01 18:18:00
         67037       2006-06-22 01:04:00
         67037       2004-07-31 18:30:00
         67037       2004-08-04 14:09:00
         67037       2005-04-20 18:06:00
         67037       2006-06-15 16:55:00
         111993        NA                        2006-06-21 17:31:45          2006-06-24 01:42:41
```

I have tried `foverlaps` this does not handle date/time values, only date values so this is ruled out. I also tried JOIN from `sqldf` library but this only does INNER JOINS , not OUTER JOINS so this is also ruled out. Not sure how to accomplish this. Any help or advise is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting? It's not clear what you want - are there supposed to be two NA? You want separate rows for the second dataset values with NA in the submitted?

Comment: @CalumYou, good question yes two NA in the `Application_SubmittedDate` column. You are correct. For example, NA is generated in the `Application_SubmittedDate` column for ID 65048 because there are no `Application_SubmittedDate` values that are within the `2006-06-21 17:31:45          2006-06-24 01:42:4`

Comment: What happens if more than one row in `Application_SubmittedDate` is between the `Application_ProcessStartDate` and `Application_ProcessEndDate`? Can that happen?

Comment: Also, you say "within those ID merge those from df1...". So should we only keep rows from df1 that have a submitted date within a matching start-end pair in df2? Your output doesn't look like that at all - only one row would satisfy that

Comment: @CalumYou, yes that is a perfectly valid situation. There can be more than one row in `Application_SubmittedDate` that can be between `Application_ProcessStartDate and Application_ProcessEndDate`. This would create a row **similar** to this `65048       2005-02-20 16:58:00         2005-02-20 12:44:22          2005-02-23 06:07:45 ` as shown in the expected output. Provided the id also matches

Comment: @CalumYou, Ignore the "within those ID merge those from df1" if this is causing consfusion. i just mentioned this to say that the checking for `Application_SubmittedDate` should happen between `Application_ProcessStartDate and Application_ProcessEndDate` for matching IDs. Ignore this sentence. The output should be exactly like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new `dplyr` version 1.1, joins have been significantly updated to be able to do your task with few lines.

The solution uses the new `join_by` function, which helps when you want to merge based on data "between" dates.

I have provided a simple solution below, which uses very few lines of code!

```
## make sure dplyr 1.1 or above!
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = join_by(ID, between(Application_SubmittedDate, 
                                          Application_ProcessStartDate,
                                          Application_ProcessEndDate)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The description in the question seems unclear but maybe you want one of these left joins.  For the data shown in the question these produce 32 and 3 rows respectively.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate,
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate
       from df1 a left join df2 b
       on a.ID = b.ID and 
          a.Application_SubmittedDate between 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate and
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate")

sqldf("select a.*, 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate,
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate
       from df2 b left join df1 a
       on a.ID = b.ID and 
          a.Application_SubmittedDate between 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate and
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate")
```

or possibly you are looking for the union of the two:

```
sqldf("select a.*, 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate,
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate
       from df1 a left join df2 b
       on a.ID = b.ID and 
          a.Application_SubmittedDate between 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate and
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate

union

select a.*, 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate,
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate
       from df2 b left join df1 a
       on a.ID = b.ID and 
          a.Application_SubmittedDate between 
              b.Application_ProcessStartDate and
              b.Application_ProcessEndDate")
```

Comment: @Gronthendiek, that was slick, :) I did some changes to your suggestion and it worked.

Comment: @EmilyFassbender You should accept the answer if it worked for you. It will be helpful for future user in that way. Thanks.

Comment: @Gronthendieck May be you want to merge result of those 2 separate results set to arrive at final result. It would be good mention it in answer.

Comment: Maybe that is what the poster wanted but we don't really know.  `sqldf("... union ...")` would give them both.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be achieved using `data.table`. The approach will be join `df1` and `df2` for both `right_join` and `left_join` and then merge the both.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)


rhs_join <- df1[df2, 
                .(i.ID, x.Application_SubmittedDate, i.Application_ProcessStartDate, 
                  i.Application_ProcessEndDate),
                on = .(ID = ID, Application_SubmittedDate >= Application_ProcessStartDate,
                       Application_SubmittedDate <= Application_ProcessEndDate)][,.(ID = i.ID, Application_SubmittedDate = x.Application_SubmittedDate,
    Application_ProcessStartDate = i.Application_ProcessStartDate,
    Application_ProcessEndDate = i.Application_ProcessEndDate)]

lhs_join <- df2[df1, 
                .(i.ID, Application_SubmittedDate, x.Application_ProcessStartDate,
                  x.Application_ProcessEndDate),
                on = .(ID = ID, Application_ProcessStartDate <= Application_SubmittedDate,
                       Application_ProcessEndDate >= Application_SubmittedDate)][,.(ID = i.ID, Application_SubmittedDate = Application_SubmittedDate,
    Application_ProcessStartDate = x.Application_ProcessStartDate,
    Application_ProcessEndDate = x.Application_ProcessEndDate)]


#Merge both data.frames
merge(rhs_join, lhs_join, all=TRUE)
```

## Result

```
ID Application_SubmittedDate Application_ProcessStartDate Application_ProcessEndDate
 1:   6972       2001-05-25 17:14:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
 2:   6972       2001-05-30 16:57:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
 3:   6972       2002-06-04 18:11:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
.....
.....
.....
23:  63457       2001-12-05 04:16:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
24:  65048                      <NA>          2006-06-21 17:31:45        2006-06-24 01:42:41
25:  65048       2002-12-16 10:18:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
26:  65048       2003-12-29 17:52:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
27:  65048       2005-02-20 16:58:00          2005-02-20 12:44:22        2005-02-23 06:07:45
28:  67037       2004-01-01 18:18:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
29:  67037       2004-07-31 18:30:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
30:  67037       2004-08-04 14:09:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
31:  67037       2005-04-20 18:06:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
32:  67037       2006-06-15 16:55:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
33:  67037       2006-06-22 01:04:00                         <NA>                       <NA>
34: 111993                      <NA>          2006-06-21 17:31:45        2006-06-24 01:42:41
```

Comment: i am getting an error, `Error: unexpected '[' in "["
>     Application_ProcessStartDate = i.Application_ProcessStartDate,
Error: unexpected ',' in "    Application_ProcessStartDate = i.Application_ProcessStartDate,"
>     Application_ProcessEndDate = i.Application_ProcessEndDate)]
Error: unexpected ')' in "    Application_ProcessEndDate = i.Application_ProcessEndDate)"`

Comment: @EmilyFassbender You can try it now. Actually few line break were introduced while trying to avoid scroll bar.

Comment: @EmilyFassbender I must appreciate your well explained question. Good work.