# How to merge between dates

Tags: r, date, merge

I have 2 dataframes that look like this:

```
df1
       ID   Drugname                    Startdate    Enddate     Dose   
      <dbl> <chr>                       <date>       <date>      <chr>    
1   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G        2008-04-04  2008-04-12  2. DA   
2   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G        2009-07-05  2009-07-12  2. AB   
3   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 5MG/G         2009-11-22  2009-12-05  2. AB   
4   111xxx  TERBINAFINE TABL 250MG      2009-07-06  2009-08-11  1.1T    
5   111xxx  CLOZAPINE TABL 25MG         2005-06-01  2005-06-28  N 2T    
6   111xxx  CLOZAPINE TABL 25MG         2005-07-01  2005-07-28  N 2T    
7   222xxx  MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG   2000-04-11  2000-04-24  1.1T    
8   222xxx  MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG   2012-03-17  2012-03-25  1.1T    
etc.
```

```
df2
       ID    (...) DATE_RESULT v1    v2      
1:   111xxx        2007-11-28  <NA>  165   
2:   111xxx        2009-07-08  <NA>  105 
3:   222xxx        2009-08-24  <NA>  125         
4:   222xxx        2012-03-27    66  20       
etc.
```

I would like to merge `df1` and `df2` to  look like this:

```
       ID    (...) DATE_RESULT v1    v2   Drugname1 Drugname2   NearDrug
1:   111xxx        2007-11-28  <NA>  165  NA        NA          NA
2:   111xxx        2009-07-08  <NA>  105  LAMISIL   TERBINAFINE NA
3:   222xxx        2009-08-24  <NA>  125  NA        NA          NA
4:   222xxx        2012-03-27    66  20   NA        NA          MAGNESIUM
etc.
```

I would like to merge these by `ID` only when `DATE_RESULT` in `df2` falls between `Startdate` and `Enddate` in `df1`. As `ID`s can have multiple `Drugname`s, I would like them to be merged in the same row after each other as seen in row 2 of new df.

Then I would like another merge/column (and I do not know if this is possible),  I would like to merge by `ID` only when `DATE_RESULT` in `df2` comes max 7 days after `Enddate` in `df1`, creating column `Neardrug`, as seen in row 4 of the new df.

For the first issue I have tried this: [r merge by id and date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079412/r-merge-by-id-and-date-between-two-dates), but that doesnt quite give me my desired new dataframe and im too rooky to alter that code.

I would like to keep all data in `df2` and not `df1`.
All information has been altered for obvious reasons.

Comment: df1 row 4 Enddate < Startdate => typo?

Comment: indeed typo, thanks!

Comment: Except if you switch Startdate and Enddate eg in row 4 of df1, the DATE_RESULT in df2 will not fit to ypur expected results. Pls validate your data once more and make your example a bit more reproducible check here with regards to R reprex https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: From what I understand, from your first requirement you want df2.DATE_RESULT between df1.Startdate and df1.Enddate. 
Also from the second requirement you want df2.DATE_RESULT between df1.Startdate and df1.Enddate+7. That is, a margin of tolerance. So requirement 2 encompasses requirement 1 by giving it a wider range. Is this understanding correct.

Comment: @user2332849 I have edited my post! No, not a wider range. I would like a new column (NearDrug) that only contains drugnames if df2.DATE_RESULT comes max 7 days after df1.Enddate for the same ID.

Comment: @GWD Sorry, I see that I've have made a mess in the rush, I have edited my post to make it more comprehensible!

Comment: So the only join condition you want is df2.DATE_RESULT between d1.Startdate and d1.Enddate + 7. Is this correct.

Comment: @user2332849 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty then! Let's divide your problem in two parts. First part is to perform said join by date, and second part is have the many results spread over columns, not rows.

**Part 1**
Although `data.table` can do the trick, I advise in favor of using `sqldf` which allows you to use a SQL syntax, which is much more readable, intuitive and scalable should you want to change your logical conditions or make them more complex.

```
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
result <- sqldf("
  select 
    df2.*,
    df1.Drugname,
    case
      when df1.ID is null then NULL
      when df2.DATE_RESULT between df1.Startdate and df1.Enddate then 'Drugname' 
      else 'Neardrug' 
    end as situation
    from df2
    left join df1
      on df1.ID = df2.id 
        and df2.DATE_RESULT between df1.Startdate and date(df1.Enddate, '+7 days')
")

print(result)
      ID DATE_RESULT v1  v2                  Drugname situation
1 111xxx  2007-11-28 NA 165                      <NA>      <NA>
2 111xxx  2009-07-08 NA 105      LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G  Drugname
3 111xxx  2009-07-08 NA 105    TERBINAFINE TABL 250MG  Drugname
4 222xxx  2009-08-24 NA 125                      <NA>      <NA>
5 222xxx  2012-03-27 66  20 MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG  Neardrug
```

As you can see, the query already returns a column named `situation`, which can be 'Drugname' or 'Neardrug'.

**Part 2**
Now you'd like spread the results of many rows for the same ID, to become columns. The ideal format is to keep they as they are, in a data frame of rows and columns, with no repetition columns. This is called the `tidy` format and it's what is normally used by several libraries in R as a standard, having several advantages.

So we may consider the column-wide format as a formatting for printout, to make it more readable. There are other concerns, too. If you have too many columns and their contents are too long, it may become difficult to manage. But let's do it.

In order to do that, we first need to create sequencing names for situations 'Drugname' into 'Drugname1', 'Drugname2', etc. Same thing for 'Neardrug' -> 'Neardrug1', 'Neardrug2', etc.

```
library(dplyr)

sequenced_result <- result %>%
  arrange(ID, DATE_RESULT, situation, Drugname) %>%
  group_by(ID, situation) %>%
  mutate(sequencing = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(colname = ifelse(is.na(situation), "Drugname1", paste0(situation, sequencing))) %>%
  ungroup()


print(sequenced_result)
  ID     DATE_RESULT    v1    v2 Drugname                  situation sequencing colname  
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                     <chr>          <int> <chr>    
1 111xxx 2007-11-28     NA   165 NA                        NA                 1 Drugname1
2 111xxx 2009-07-08     NA   105 LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G      Drugname           1 Drugname1
3 111xxx 2009-07-08     NA   105 TERBINAFINE TABL 250MG    Drugname           2 Drugname2
4 222xxx 2009-08-24     NA   125 NA                        NA                 1 Drugname1
5 222xxx 2012-03-27     66    20 MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG Neardrug           1 Neardrug1
```

We're almost there. Now all we need to do is to move the row values onto columns by doing a **pivot** operation.

```
library(tidyr)

formatted_result <- sequenced_result %>%
  select(-c(situation, sequencing)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = colname, values_from = Drugname)

print(formatted_result)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  ID     DATE_RESULT    v1    v2 Drugname1            Drugname2              Neardrug1               
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                <chr>                  <chr>                   
1 111xxx 2007-11-28     NA   165 NA                   NA                     NA                      
2 111xxx 2009-07-08     NA   105 LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G TERBINAFINE TABL 250MG NA                      
3 222xxx 2009-08-24     NA   125 NA                   NA                     NA                      
4 222xxx 2012-03-27     66    20 NA                   NA                     MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724~
```

As a finishing touch, if you want, you may show just the first word of every drug name.

```
library(stringr)

formatted_result_short <- sequenced_result %>%
  select(-c(situation, sequencing)) %>%
  mutate(Drugname = word(Drugname)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = colname, values_from = Drugname)

print(formatted_result_short)
  ID     DATE_RESULT    v1    v2 Drugname1 Drugname2   Neardrug1
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>    
1 111xxx 2007-11-28     NA   165 NA        NA          NA       
2 111xxx 2009-07-08     NA   105 LAMISIL   TERBINAFINE NA       
3 222xxx 2009-08-24     NA   125 NA        NA          NA       
4 222xxx 2012-03-27     66    20 NA        NA          MAGNESIUM
```

Comment: This did the job, thank you!! I find the "sqldf" packages also more user-friendly

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to identify

1. all drugs which have been prescribed to a person `ID` at the date a medical analysis took place `DATE_RESULT` and
2. all drugs which have been taken within the last seven days *before* the medical analysis took place.

So we need to find overlapping date ranges. This can be implemented by *aggregating in a non-equi join* using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
condense <- function(x) toString(unique(stringr::str_extract(x, "^\\w+")))
df2[, c("Drugname", "Neardrugs") := .(
  df1[df2, on = .(ID, Startdate <= DATE_RESULT, Enddate >= DATE_RESULT), 
      condense(Drugname), by = .EACHI]$V1, 
  df1[df2[, .(ID, DATE_RESULT, DRm7 = DATE_RESULT - 7L)], 
      on = .(ID, Enddate <= DATE_RESULT, Enddate >= DRm7), 
      condense(Drugname), by = .EACHI]$V1)][]
```

> ```
>        ID DATE_RESULT v1  v2             Drugname Neardrugs
> 1: 111xxx  2007-11-28 NA 165                   NA        NA
> 2: 111xxx  2009-07-08 NA 105 LAMISIL, TERBINAFINE        NA
> 3: 222xxx  2009-08-24 NA 125                   NA        NA
> 4: 222xxx  2012-03-27 66  20                   NA MAGNESIUM
> ```

#### Explanation

The expression

```
df1[df2, on = .(ID, Startdate <= DATE_RESULT, Enddate >= DATE_RESULT), 
    condense(Drugname), by = .EACHI]
```

right joins `df1` and `df2` on matching `ID` and checks that `DATE_RESULT` is within the date range `[Startdate, Enddate]` (closed intervals). The parameter `by = .EACHI` requests that the data are to be grouped and aggregated for each match. The aggregation function is `condense()` which picks the first word from each `Drugname`, drops duplicate entries, and concatenates the entries to a single character string.

The result is

> ```
>        ID  Startdate    Enddate                   V1
> 1: 111xxx 2007-11-28 2007-11-28                   NA
> 2: 111xxx 2009-07-08 2009-07-08 LAMISIL, TERBINAFINE
> 3: 222xxx 2009-08-24 2009-08-24                   NA
> 4: 222xxx 2012-03-27 2012-03-27                   NA
> ```

from which the result column `V1` is appended to `df2` as new column `Drugname`.

The expression

```
df1[df2[, .(ID, DATE_RESULT, DRm7 = DATE_RESULT - 7L)], 
    on = .(ID, Enddate <= DATE_RESULT, Enddate >= DRm7), 
    condense(Drugname), by = .EACHI]
```

is essentially the same but it checks that `Enddate` is within the date range `[DATE_RESULT - 7L, DATE_RESULT]`. As we cannot create a new column on-the-fly in the `on =` clause (which is a long standing [feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639), BTW), we have to create a helper column `DRm7` to join on.

The result is

> ```
>        ID    Enddate    Enddate        V1
> 1: 111xxx 2007-11-28 2007-11-21        NA
> 2: 111xxx 2009-07-08 2009-07-01        NA
> 3: 222xxx 2009-08-24 2009-08-17        NA
> 4: 222xxx 2012-03-27 2012-03-20 MAGNESIUM
> ```

from which the result column `V1` is appended to `df2` as new column `Neardrugs`.

#### Data

```
df1 <- readr::read_table("
i       ID  Drugname                    Startdate   Enddate     Dose   
1   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G        2008-04-04  2008-04-12  2. DA   
2   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 10MG/G        2009-07-05  2009-07-12  2. AB   
3   111xxx  LAMISIL CREME 5MG/G         2009-11-22  2009-12-05  2. AB   
4   111xxx  TERBINAFINE TABL 250MG      2009-07-06  2009-08-11  1.1T    
5   111xxx  CLOZAPINE TABL 25MG         2005-06-01  2005-06-28  N 2T    
6   111xxx  CLOZAPINE TABL 25MG         2005-07-01  2005-07-28  N 2T    
7   222xxx  MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG   2000-04-11  2000-04-24  1.1T    
8   222xxx  MAGNESIUM HYD KAUWT 724MG   2012-03-17  2012-03-25  1.1T  ",
                         col_types = "_ccDDc")

df2 <- readr::read_table("
i    ID            DATE_RESULT v1    v2      
1:   111xxx        2007-11-28  <NA>  165   
2:   111xxx        2009-07-08  <NA>  105 
3:   222xxx        2009-08-24  <NA>  125         
4:   222xxx        2012-03-27    66  20     ",
                         col_types = "_cDii")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm as well. Thank you for the edit and explanation!