# R: Merge "Between" using Base R

Tags: sql, r, join, dplyr, data-manipulation

Suppose I have the following tables (note: the dates appear as factors in my problem):

```
table_1 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "125"), 
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id = as.factor(table_1$id)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id = c("123", "121", "125", "126"), 
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id = as.factor(table_2$id)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)
```

I would like to perform (some type of) "join" on these two tables (for now it doesn't matter, e.g. right join, inner join, etc.) using the following conditions:

**1)** if table_1$id = table_2$id

AND

**2)** if table_1$date BETWEEN(table_2$date_2,table_2$date_3)

I found a previous question on Stackoverflow which demonstrates how to do this using the "SQLDF" library: [r merge by id and date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079412/r-merge-by-id-and-date-between-two-dates)

```
library(sqldf)

final = sqldf("select a.*, b.*
           
       from table_1 a left join table_2 b
       on a.id = b.id and 
          a.date_1 between 
              b.date_2 and
              b.date_3")
head(final)
#for some reason, this produces duplicate rows, I don't know why



id     date_1  id     date_2     date_3
1 123 2010-01-31 123 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
2 123 2010-01-31 123 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
3 125 2015-01-31 125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
4 125 2018-01-31 125 2010-01-31 2020-01-31

#optional: remove duplicates
final_no_dup <- final[!duplicated(final$id),]
```

**My Question:** Is there a way to perform the above "join" using Base R? If this is not possible in Base R, can this be done in "dplyr"?

Comment: THose are not duplicates. The first 2 rows of your table 1 are exactly the same.

Comment: You don't need to write "I am working with the R programming language." This is what the [tag:r] tag for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way in `dplyr`

```r
table_1 %>%
      left_join(table_2, by = "id") %>%
      mutate(across(2:4, ~as.Date(.x))) %>%
      filter(date_1 <= max(date_3, date_2), date_1 >= min(date_2, date_3)) %>%
      distinct()
    
       id     date_1     date_2     date_3
    1 123 2010-01-31 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
    2 125 2015-01-31 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
    3 125 2018-01-31 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
```

## Base `R`

```
table_3 <- merge(x = table_1, y = table_2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
table_3 <- table_3[table_3$date_1 <= max(table_3$date_2, table_3$date_3) && table_3$date_1 >= min(table_3$date_2,table_3$date_3)]
table_3[!duplicated(table_3),]
```

Comment: @ Park: Thank you so much for your answer! Can you please tell me why the line of code "  mutate(across(2:4, ~as.Date(.x))) %>%" is required? thank you!

Comment: @stats555 Those variables were factor, so I need to make them as date to use `max` and `min` between `date_2` and `date_3`.

Comment: @ Park: Thank you for your reply! Do you think it is better to somehow change the date format of all date variables in "table_1" and "table_2" BEFORE running the join?

Comment: @ Park : I am still curious if there is a way to do this in Base R?

Comment: @stats555 If those date are date, it would be better not to code them as a factor.  If you do not add `as.factor` part, you also do not need `mutate(across(2:4, ~as.Date(.x))) %>%` line. And I'm not sure about Base R, that I'm not good at base R join

Comment: @ Park: Thank you for your reply! In my original problem, I was given the dates as "factor". I think the dates can be converted by using the following code "table_1$date_1 = as.Date(table_1$date_1) ;
table_2$date_2 = as.Date(table_2$date_2) ;
table_2$date_3 = as.Date(table_2$date_3)" . I will try to convert these dates into "date" formats and run your code without "mutate(across(2:4, ~as.Date(.x))) %>%". Thank you!

Comment: @ Park: If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195177/r-joins-based-on-or-statements Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 Sure. I'll take a look into it. By the way, I add the base R version above.