# R: Multiple Joins in SQLDF

Tags: sql, r, join, data-manipulation

I have the following two tables in R (the "Dates" appear as "Factors" in my data):

```
table_1 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "125"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id = as.factor(table_1$id)
table_1$id2 = as.factor(table_1$id2)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "125"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id = as.factor(table_2$id)
table_2$id2 = as.factor(table_2$id2)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)
```

I am trying to perform an "inner join" if either Condition 1 OR Condition 2 is true:

**Condition_1**

if table_1$id = table_2$id
AND

if table_1$date BETWEEN(table_2$date_2,table_2$date_3)

**Condition_2**

if table_1$id2 = table_2$id2

**Question:** I tried to use the code below to achieve the above task:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select distinct * 
  from table_1 a inner join table_2 b
  on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3) and 
     a.id = b.id or (a.id2 = b.id2)")
```

The above code successfully complied and ran, But I am not sure if the logic is correct.

**Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [R: Joins based on "OR" Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195177/r-joins-based-on-or-statements)

Comment: The query, as written, looks logically correct to me.  Have you tried running/testing your R code?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : Thank you for your reply! The code seems to compile and run - however, I am not sure if the logic is correct.

Comment: (1) I haven't verified, but your `(..) and (..) or (..)` to me leaves room for ambiguity, visually if nothing else. In those situations, I generally wrap in parens so I know how things are cascading. This query is different paren-wise than what G.Grothendieck offered in the [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200975/3358272), did you change parens intentionally? (2) You said *"not sure if this is correct"*, based on what? Do you know what the output should be, and is this not producing that output? "Not sure" it not a good "bug report".

Comment: @ r2Evans: thank you for your reply! I tried to change the logic from the previous question (that you cited) - however, I am not sure if I have correctly changed the logic. In the future, I will remember to use a better choice of words. Thank you!

Comment: Based on the conditions you state (where `date_1` is relevant if `id=id` but not otherwise), I'd think your logic is fine. **However**, you said you are `trying to perform an "inner join"` yet your query uses `left join`; that's a mis-step logically, depending on how you expect misses to play out.

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you for your reply! re left join: sorry about that - my mistake

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: Thank you for your reply! I did not know this! I have often heard people use the word "compile" while referring to R and SQL - I guess this is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `and` takes precedence over `or` in SQL so the `on` clause in the question is the same as `(... and ...) or (...)`.  In the original post there was code eliminating duplicates which is why I had added distinct but in this one there is no mention of that so you likely don't need it.

Comment: Although R  and SQL are not compiled they are translated to byte code and the compiler package that comes with R does refer to it as compiling.  You can see a representation of the byte code for R like this (using an example from the package): `library(compile); f <- function(x) x + 1; fc <- compile(f); disassemble(fc)` and for sqlite like this: `sqldf("explain select ...)` where ... is the rest of the SQL statement.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck : Thank you for your reply! So in the end, is the code I posted in this question correct? Thank you!